# npm install zsh: command not found: npm

Tags: node.js, npm, zsh

I just reinstalled node on my laptop and trying to install packaged in project. I installed node via brew and Im using MacOS.

```
npm install
zsh: command not found: npm
```

Comment: Check - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75472094/5348972

Answer (score 9):

The solution below actually solved my issue

https://superuser.com/questions/1403007/zsh-npm-node-nvm-command-not-found-after-installing-ohmyzsh

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  
# This loads nvm bash_completion
```

this line of code on your .zshrc file to do that type vim ~/.zshrc than add the following lines in the bottom and to save the file click ctrl than press :wq! to save file in vim you can also use nano

Answer (score 3):

For me, I encountered the same issue as you did.

How I fixed:

First, checking whether npm is installed or not by checking its version:

```
npm --version
```

If the terminal still shows no npm not found, then type:

```
nvm install --lts
```

This command will trigger updating node package manager to the latest version.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Heimson Cool! Glad that it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your binaries for npm are in `/usr/local/share/npm/bin`. Is this in your path environment variable?

If not export it at `~/.zshrc` with `export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -e "\n. $(brew --prefix asdf)/libexec/asdf.sh" >> ${ZDOTDIR:-~}/.zshrc
```

The above command suits for `asdf` with `zsh` situation. More details in this [link](https://daverhay.com/posts/shell/asdf/).

Answer (score -2):

You should run `nvm use node` every time you startup a new terminal.