# zsh: command not found: npm in the command line

Tags: node.js

I downloaded nodejs from nodejs.org on my Mac. When I type node in the command line in the terminal I get the following:

```
davidd.christie@Davids-MacBook-Pro ~ % node
Welcome to Node.js v12.18.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> .exit
davidd.christie@Davids-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls
Applications    Documents   Library     Music       Postman
Desktop     Downloads   Movies      Pictures    Public
davidd.christie@Davids-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd Desktop 
davidd.christie@Davids-MacBook-Pro Desktop % ls
UBS Candidate Benefits Modeler.pdf  my-express-server
intro-to-node               node-course
davidd.christie@Davids-MacBook-Pro Desktop % cd intro-to-node
davidd.christie@Davids-MacBook-Pro intro-to-node % npm init
zsh: command not found: npm
davidd.christie@Davids-MacBook-Pro intro-to-node%
```

It is my understanding that npm automatically downloads once you download node.  I tried to initiate npm and got the following message (please see the above code in typed in the command line):

zsh: command not found: npm

I am not sure what to do from here.  I have been looking at some of the code on here.  I am so confused as to what to do.  I am fairly new to coding.  Can someone please help and out step by step as to what I need to do?  I would be forever grateful.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you have installed node. First check the version of your node.

```
node --version
```

It should give your node version. In my case it is `v10.15.0`. Now to find where this node is coming from use command.

```
which node
```

It will give you output as `/Users/samundra/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/node`. It shows that my node is installed at `/Users/samundra/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/`. Usually `npm` and `node` both are placed at same location `$NODE_HOME/bin/node`, `$NODE_HOME/bin/npm`. Here `$NODE_HOME` is `/Users/samundra/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0`.

If we further check where `$NODE_HOME/bin/npm` by using

```
ls -al /Users/samundra/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/npm
```

We find that it's linked to `npm-cli.js`

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 samundra  staff  38 May 11 12:08 /Users/samundra/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

So, `npm` is symlinked to `npm-cli.js` which can be found at `$NODE_HOME/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`.

With this information now you can figure out whether your node and npm has been installed properly or not. Furthermore, If this is your first time installing node, try closing and re-opening your terminal. Most terminals need to re-initiate sessions after populating environment variables which are used based on installation method that you have used.

I hope this has answered your curiosity. If you feel so then please do not forget to mark it as answer.

**Suggestion:**

When you feel you have understood how node and npm work. Then you can move to use [Node Version Manager (Nvm)](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). It allows you to install multiple versions of node on same machine. You can switch between them using commands like

```
 nvm list: List available node version
 nvm use {node_version}: Install Node version and use it
```

This is quite helpful when you will have to work on different projects that require different version of nodes.

Comment: Hi Samundra,  

Thank you for taking the time out of your business schedule to get back to me.  

I downloaded node.js directly from the nodejs website. The node version I have is below: 

davidd.christie@Davids-MacBook-Pro ~ % node
Welcome to Node.js v12.18.0.

When I type the below,

Which node

I get  /usr/local/bin/node

What would I do from here?

Comment: A little late to be of use to OP, but as this is a good and thorough answer I thought it'd be worth commenting. 

To navigate to the usr/local/bin/node folder and check that node and npm are installed in the same place you will need to get the folder to show, as it is hidden by default. If you open finder, then press command + shift + g to open the dialogue box and you can then type in what you want. In this case "/usr", now you have temporary access to the folder and can drag it into you favourites panel in finder for easier access at another time.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Actually you need to edit your .zshrc file

1. Open .zshrc file - `sudo nano ~/.zshrc`
2. Add `source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`
3. Save file and restart terminal